# VB.net v2.0 error: 'restart' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Application'

Tags: vb.net

From what I read, vb.net version 2.0 and greater allow for the `Application.restart()` statement, but when I add the statement to my VB.net program, I get this error:

> 'restart' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Application'

Please advise if you have had this issue and figured out how to resolve it. I don't understand why something so simple is creating an error.

Comment: I read the MSDN page and is says `Requires IsUnrestricted permission.` if that helps. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.restart(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you using a windows forms application?  Do you have a reference to System.Windows.Forms?

Comment: Is that a compilation error or a run-time exception?

Comment: That's a possibility - I am looking into using IsUnrestricted permission now, but I am not familiar with using it, and I am having some issues getting that to work too.

Comment: Yes, I have a reference to System.Windows.Forms. This is a compilation error

Comment: FYI I could not resolve so I created a workaround by creating a function to update only the columns on the form that needed to be refreshed